# docker-compose, migrate from links. (Flask app + mysql)

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have followed the flask mega tutorial currently done the Docker part. I tried to make a docker-compose.yml which wokrs great, but I understand that I shouldnt use "links" anymore.

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xix-deployment-on-docker-containers/page/0#comments

I've tried using "depends_on"  -mysql, but that doesn't work. Also adding mysql:dbserver, which restults in "undefined" when I run docker compose up.

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
      build: .
      ports:
      - 8000:5000

      environment:
        SECRET_KEY: my-secret-key
        DATABASE_URL: mysql+pymysql://microblog:pw@dbserver/microblog
      links:
      - mysql:dbserver

    mysql:
      image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
      environment:
        MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: random
        MYSQL_DATABASE: microblog
        MYSQL_USER: microblog
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: pw
```

Would really appreciate if someone could help me "rewriting" the "links" part to something not being depreciated as links now are. 
Also other comments on the yml file is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The names of the various `services:` blocks are directly usable as hostnames.  In your example, remove `links:`, and change the database URL to be `mysql+pymysql://microblog:pw@mysql/microblog` (changing the hostname part).

You do not need to specify `hostname:`, `container_name:`, `expose:`, or `networks:`.  `depends_on:` ensures that a `docker-compose up web` will also start the database, but isn't necessary for networking to work.  If either container specifies `network_mode: host` connection scheme doesn't work (and you can usually remove this option).

`ports:` is also optional, though it's helpful if you're trying to access a given service from outside Docker space.  If you're trying to remap ports using `ports:` (or if you don't have `ports:` at all) you need to connect to the port that the container is using internally, not the published port number (in the case of `ports:`, the *second* port number; if a third service was involved it could reach `http://web:5000`).

[Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation has extended details.